# convert an array of objects to a dataset that can be feed into a jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an array like below,

```
["abc", "xyz", "mno"]
```

now I want to convert it to an another array which has wrapped each element with a square bracket, like below:

```
["abc"], ["xyz"], ["mno"]
```

so I can use this data set to create single column datatable.

Comment: Just got an idea, I think I can use array splice method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = ["abc", "xyz", "mno"];
var aa = [];
for(i in a){
  aa.push([a[i]]);
}
console.log(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk function to convert all element to new array

```
$test = ["abc", "xyz", "mno"];

$new = array_walk($test, 'elementtoArray');

function elementtoArray($value, $key) {
    return array($key => $value);
}

print_r($new);
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/5wdLg255/)

```
var arr = ["abc", "xyz", "mno"];
newarr = [];
console.log(arr);
for (var i in arr) {
    newarr.push([arr[i]]);
        }  

console.log(newarr);
```